# How do I read text from the clipboard in a Javascript web page script with Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-applications, clipboard

According to the [Browser compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API#browser_compatibility), Firefox's implementation of the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) only supports reading the clipboard in browser extensions (given the `clipboardRead` extension permission). How can I read text from the clipboard in a web page script? `navigator.clipboard.readText` is `undefined`. I would be willing to write an extension, but I don't know how to make something like a synchronous "function call" from page script to extension that would return the text read by the extension.

Comment: Would pasting the content to an invisible element and then reading the content of that element suffice?

Comment: Yes, anything that works is fine

Comment: Where is your script running from? `navigator.clipboard.readText` works fine for me. From a chrome extension you may be able to use `document.execCommand("paste");`

Comment: As opposed to Firefox, Chrome and Edge support `navigator.clipboard.readText` in page scripts. I don't want to use `document.execCommand` because it is deprecated. Besides, it didn't work for me with `paste` in a page script in Firefox (it returned `false`). According to the MDN documentation, `paste` is _Disabled for web content_.

Comment: Can you share an example of your code? Maybe a minimally reproducible example? I am not getting any errors using `navigator.clipboard.readText`. Are you using it over HTTPS or localhost? Chrome will not allow navigator actions over HTTP

Comment: I'm using HTTPS. I think `navigator.clipboard` requires a _secure context_. Are you using Firefox or Chrome for your test? And if you are using Firefox, are you testing an extension or a web page?